# Saving new methods of class using Ruby metaprogramming

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I just discovered Ruby's metaprogramming (after 7 years of using Ruby, it was about time!) and I have this question:

Assuming I run a program that uses `class_eval` and other metaporgramming functions to add methods to a class, is there an easy way, when re-running the same program, to have these new methods already defined, or do I have to program my own system which, every time `class_eval` is used, also save the generated code in a file in order to re-evaluate it the next time I run the program?

Thanks

Comment: Your code (or pieces of code, or methods) should note rely on a state that is created outside their scope (in the form of on-the-fly generated, saved and reused methods), because it makes results erratic. This is the same reason you should avoid global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how it's done. A proper way is, when you run the program next time, to run all those calls to `define_method`, `class_eval` (and whatnot) again and define methods in run-time.

Imagine what would happen if generated methods persisted in your source code? Would you like your `attr_accessor` to replace itself with two new methods?

What if you're writing such a meta-method yourself and you change it. How do you think all those saved generated methods will be updated?

I don't know where you read about metaprogramming, but I strongly recommend this book: [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby). It should clear your head. :)

Comment: Indeed I didn't consider the case where methods are overwritten and the order methods are defined has an importance. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can not (with eval, and self-assembled strings you could, but that is not metaprogramming anymore) and should not do that, even ruby's standard library is re-evaluated on program launch.

Another possibility would be forking, unicorn is a good example for that. Evaluate all your method definitions, and then start spawning child processes, which are copies of the "master" process. This saves you the time of re-evaluating all your code, as forks are pretty fast compared to that.